# Cómo se puede diferenciar entre clientes en socket.io?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket, socket.io, websocket

Estoy programando una aplicación en tiempo real usando `socket.io` y `node.js`, necesito emitir mensajes según el cliente en especifico, es decir cada cliente tiene un flujo de datos independiente, después de loguearse y una serie de verificaciones.

Este es mi código de servidor (el controlador desde donde se ejecuta el socket):

```
//Mostramos el 'dashboard' de dispositivo
const getSingleDevice= async(req,res)=>{

/*Realizamos una busqueda dentro de la base de datos*/
const device = await Device.findById( req.params.id );

console.log('device: ', device)

//Importamos la conexion del servidor de Sockets
const connectionSocket = require('../../lib/socketManager').connection();

//Importamos la conexion del servidor mqtt
const connectionMqtt = require('../../lib/mqttManager').connection();

//Creamos una funcion que se ejecutara cada vez que recibimos un dato por mqtt
//En este caso enviamos por websockets
let sendToSocket=async (d)=>{

    //Conversion de los datos
    let data = JSON.parse(d.replace(/'/g,"\""));

    connectionSocket.sendEvent('temperature', data.temperature);
    connectionSocket.sendEvent('humidity', data.humidity);

    //console.log('Enviando al Socket: ',data.token);  
    //console.log('Enviando al Socket: ',data.temperature);  
    //console.log('Enviando al Socket: ',data.humidity); 

    //Verificamos el 'token'
    //Notese que dentro de 'decoded' se encuentra el 'id' del 'user'
    //al que le corresponde dicho 'id'

    await jwt.verify(data.token, config.secret, (error, decoded) => {

        //Si NO existe el 'user' devolvemos un estado de error
        if(error){
            console.log('Token No valido')
            //return res.status(404).send('El TOKEN ES INCORRRECTO o hay un error de servidor');
        }else{

            //Mostramos en consola
            //console.log('token: ', data.token);
            //console.log('topic', topic);
            //console.log('decoded: ', decoded);

            if(decoded.id===device.userOwnerId){

                console.log('Identificador: ', device.userOwnerId+'/'+device._id);

                //Enviamos por el socket
                connectionSocket.sendEvent('temperature', data.temperature);
                connectionSocket.sendEvent('humidity', data.humidity);
                connectionSocket.sendEvent('id', device.userOwnerId+'/'+device._id);

            }else{

                console.log('Identificador no valido: ', device.userOwnerId+'/'+device._id);

            }

        };     

    });

};

//Armamos el topic
topic=device.userOwnerId+'/'+device._id;
console.log('topic: ', topic); 

//Registramos un dato recibido por mqtt y lo enviamos al 'socket'
connectionMqtt.registerMQTT(topic, sendToSocket);

//Renderizamos
res.render('devices/detail-device', {device});}
```

A un cliente hecho en `HTML` `javascript`, estoy usando `handlebars` para servir el contenido dinámicamente, pero no si si tendrá algo que ver o si puedo pasarle parámetro de forma dinámica para escuchar datos según el cliente conectado:

```
//Defeinimos la direccion del servidor
//VERIFICAR PRIMERO
const host = 'http://192.168.1.106:3000';

//Almacenamos el dato proveniente del servidor
let sensorStatus = 0;

//Creamos una conexion socket con el servidor
//VERIFICAR la direccion EL SERVIDOR DEL API DE DESTINO Primero
const connection = io(host);

//Ejecutamos tan pronto se cargue la ventana
window.onload = function(){   

//connection.emit('Prueba', 'Hello server from client');

//Escichamos el evento 'connect' para verificar la conexion con el servidor
//Mostramos en consola si todo ha salido bien
connection.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Enlazado con el servidor: ', host); 
});

//Recibimos del servidor del valor por medio de websockets
connection.on('temperature', function(data){

    console.log('temperature: ', data);

    //Cambiamos el valor de la grafica
    updateGauge(data);

});

//Recibimos del servidor del valor por medio de websockets
connection.on('humidity', function(data){

    console.log('humidity: ', data);

});

//Recibimos del servidor del valor por medio de websockets
connection.on('id', function(data){

    console.log('id: ', data);

});

};
```

Sin embargo, si emito data por el `socket`, dicha data es recibida **por todos los clientes**, sin importar si estén logueados o no, de hecho estoy usando `jwt` y dos tipos de id diferentes para poder diferenciar a los usuarios.

¿Como puedo diferenciar a los clientes y enviar la data a un cliente/usuario en especifico?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta, estás en SO en español

Comment: deja un comentario cuando la traduzcas y la vuelvo a abrir

Comment: No me deja editar la pregunta ¿como lo hago?

Comment: Ya lo traduje ..